# Select distinct Values from mysql with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

i've one table pages. In this table i am having records pages table where some of the pages having duplicate entries. I want to fetch unique pages from the table on the basis of city_id. Where i m executing this query :-

```
SELECT distinct pagename FROM tbl_page 
WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' order by pagename
```

This query returning me distinct records as 2608. I want to fetch the id and section id of this pages as well in my query. So when i m executing this query

```
SELECT distinct pagename,id,section_id FROM tbl_page 
WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' order by pagename
```

At this time it is not returning distinct value. It is returning 3400 records which are duplicates. Can anyone tell me what i m doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look at the `GROUP BY` statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know what results you are expecting but maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT pagename,id,section_id FROM tbl_page 
WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' 
GROUP BY pagename, id, section
order by pagename
```

if you like to have unique pagenames you should:

```
SELECT pagename,id,section_id FROM tbl_page 
WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' 
GROUP BY pagename
order by pagename
```

But you may have different id/section_id values for one pagename so i think the value for id and section_id will be the value from the first row where the pagename was found.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but using this query also returning me the duplicate values.

Comment: What do you mean by dublicate values? Dublicate pagenames? Yes. But unique pagename, id, section combinations.

Comment: if you like to have unique pagenames you need to `GROUP BY pagename` only. But you may have different sections/ids for the same pagename.

Comment: Maybe you should show us your create table statement, some sample data and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT will return only distinct rows, so, You could also switch to GROUP BY instead.

```
SELECT `pagename`, `id`, `section_id` FROM `tbl_page`
WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78'
GROUP BY 'pagename', 'section_id', `id`  
ORDER BY `pagename` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT always works on a single column. Alternatively you can use GROUP BY keyword which can be used on multiple columns. See the below query:

```
SELECT pagename,id,section_id FROM tbl_page WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' GROUP BY pagename,id,section_id ORDER BY pagename
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but using this query also returning me the duplicate values.

Comment: Can you share the resultsets you are getting?. You also share the screenshot of your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be solved :
You need to use distinct over complete rows Like that way :

```
SELECT pagename,id,section_id,DISTINCT(*) FROM tbl_page WHERE status = '0' AND city_id = '78' GROUP BY pagename,id,section_id ORDER BY pagename
```